# How to get faster than 1Hz CoreLocation refresh rate?

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, core-location

If I use CoreLocation by itself with the highest accuracy possible, I get an update once a second or 1Hz. However, if I have an external bluetooth connected GPS unit with a 10Hz refresh rate, I still only get a response from CoreLocation at 1Hz.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or will CoreLocation return a result at 1Hz no matter what?

Would I be required to connect to the bluetooth GPS unit directly using a bluetooth framework to get the 10Hz refresh rate data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are external GPS units, such as those from [Bad Elf](https://bad-elf.com), that will be used by iOS instead of the internal GPS receiver, but the abstraction layer of Core Location hides their details; you just get more accurate location.

If you want faster updates then you will need to [integrate directly with the GPS](https://bad-elf.com/pages/sdk) receiver and not use Core Location.

> The GPS SDK provides developers direct access to configure Bad Elf GPS accessories for a wide variety of use cases. The common configurations are:
>
> - Configuration of high resolution location data reporting (2-10Hz) mode
> - Fix quality indicators: number of satellites, WAAS status, raw HDOP/PDOP/VDOP values
> - UTC date and time
> - Satellites in view with elevation, azimuth, and raw SNR values

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CoreLocation does not work with any external accessories whatsoever. Thus the answer is yes, if you want to get location updates from external bluetooth GPS accessory , you'll need to work through bluetooth protocol and APIs...

Comment: I was under the impression that, if an external GPS is connected, CoreLocation grabs the location data from that instead of the internal gps chip. It seems to be the case when using, as location gets more accurate when using the unit, however Im still only getting an update every 1second.

Comment: Even if it is, it's not documented anywhere and so you can not relay on it. So the answer is still – do it yourself.

Comment: The only valid reference I've found about external GPS sources is under this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation. Specifically where it says "...including Wi-Fi, GPS, Bluetooth, magnetometer, barometer, and cellular hardware to gather data." But again, no references on any way to control it. There are some references to external GPS units that includes some SDKs to work with them directly. Maybe you can use one of them...